# JS - how to map array into array with nested objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects

```
const arr1 = [{depCode: "Dep code", typeCode: "Code", number: "Number"},
              {depCode: "123", typeCode: "12", number: "35"}];
```

How can I map them to an array of objects like below

```
expected output = [{depCode:{key: "Dep code", value: "123"}},
                 typeCode:{key: "Code", value: "12"},
                 number:{key: "Number", value: "35"}]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const obj1 = {depCode: "Dep code", typeCode: "Code", number: "Number"};

const obj2= {depCode: "123", typeCode: "12", number: "35"};

const arr = [];

Object.keys(obj1).forEach(a=> arr.push({[a]: obj2[a]}));

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score -1):

Since both obj1 and obj2 have similar schema,

```
let obj1 = {depCode: "Dep code", typeCode: "Code", number: "Number"};
let obj2 = {depCode: "123", typeCode: "12", number: "35"};
let objectKeys = Object.keys(obj1);

let resArray = objectKeys.reduce((prevValue, currValue)=>{
    prevValue.push({[currValue]: {key:obj1[currValue],value:obj2[currValue]}});
    return prevValue;
}, [])
console.log(resArray);
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jeldikk/4a92m1cx/1/) for the same